# How can I shuffle string characters

Tags: haskell

I want to shaffle string characters and I have found 'shuffle' function in Data.Random.Extras. But when I am trying to import it I get the error message:

```
*Main> import Data.Random

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `Data.Random':
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

How can I import this package?  Or maybe there are another way to shuffle string characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This package doesn't come with Haskell and needs to be installed.

Have you used `cabal` before?  You can install new packages with

```
cabal install random-extras
```

Comment: I have not used it before, but I get it :) Thanks.